# Regex - Get index of match in line

Tags: regex, text

I have sublime text or phpstorm.

I want to change this string by regex replace:

```
Hello world
```

to

```
<span class="word1">Hello</span>
<span class="word2">world</span>
```

How do it?

*My code:*

```
(\w+)
```

What instead of $index?

```
<span class="word$index">$1</span>
```

Comment: I think you should split by a negated pattern and put around the text you want (that way you can have multiple words, not just two).

Comment: you can't do like this `<span class="word$index">$1</span>`  through regex only.

Answer (score 0):

REgex:

```
^(\w+) (\w+)$
```

REplacement string:

```
<span class="word1">$1</span>\n<span class="word2">$2</span>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kS1eO8/1)

Comment: I doubt the original question was about only this specific case, though in case yes, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$re = "/\\w+/m";
    $str = "Hello world Hello2 world2";

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    var_dump( $matches);
    $out="";
    if( count($matches[0])>0) foreach($matches[0] as $k=>$v){
        $id=$k+1;
        $out .= "<span class=\"word$id\">$v</span>\n";
    }
var_dump($out);
```

**output:**

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Hello' (length=5)
      1 => string 'world' (length=5)
      2 => string 'Hello2' (length=6)
      3 => string 'world2' (length=6)

string '<span class="word1">Hello</span>
<span class="word2">world</span>
<span class="word3">Hello2</span>
<span class="word4">world2</span>
' (length=134)
```